# How could intangibility be explained?

Tags: science-based, physics

Ignoring how it happens in the first place, how could one scientifically explain a being with the ability to phase their body through solid matter, while still keeping the shape of their body from deforming?

Comment: You need to do some more research into... well, everything. You're asking a lot of "science based" questions but showing very little knowledge of basic science - for example, in this question, you want intangibility; the ability to "phase" through solid matter, while keeping the shape of their body. In currently accepted science, molecules and atoms can "collide" with each other. They also have "charges", which keep things together (and form complex molecules which everything is made of). In order for someone to "phase" through something, their atoms/molecules would have to have 0 charge (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) which allows the atoms to (hopefully) pass through the space between the object they're trying to "phase" through - but by removing the charge, you've removed the forces that keep your body shape, dissipating you into many many electrons, protons, and neutrons as all your particles are no longer held together, and don't react with anything else. The knowledge used in these 2 comments is knowledge you'd get from grade 8 science courses (and is also easily searchable via Google). As such, I'm VTCing this question. (originally as "unclear what you're asking", but I misclicked "too broad").

Comment: Another approach (although it's not based on real science as we know it) is that such a being moves one millimeter (or whatever) into hyperspace, walks "around" the wall in another dimension, and then returns to our three-dimensional space.

Comment: Since we now know classical physics forbid it how about quantum physics... if you're literally the size of atom chances are you will eventually be on the other side or perhaps inside the wall.

Comment: @Aify Well, excuse me for my middle school not having an advanced chemistry class, apparently.

Comment: @DonielF There is a way something close could happen, just highly improbable and would probably cause you to drop towards the center of the earth. You need to be able to remove every single electron from the atoms and molecules that make up your body. Provided you can keep them somewhere and get them back later and hopefully float, you can conceivably move through walls. I don't actually know what happens when you remove the electrons though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How could one scientifically explain a being with the ability to phase their body through solid matter, while still keeping the shape of their body from deforming?"

The being in question would need to possess the ability to convert their matter into mirror matter during their passage through solid matter.

> In physics, mirror matter, also called shadow matter or Alice matter, is a hypothetical counterpart to ordinary matter.

Mirror matter and ordinary matter, if they do interact, will do so very weakly. In fact, sufficiently so they could pass through each other as if they weren't there.

> Mirror matter, if it exists, would need to interact weakly with ordinary matter. This is because the forces between mirror particles are mediated by mirror bosons. With the exception of the graviton, none of the known bosons can be identical to their mirror partners. The only way mirror matter can interact with ordinary matter via forces other than gravity is via kinetic mixing of mirror bosons with ordinary bosons or via the exchange of Holdom particles.[10] These interactions can only be very weak.

This weak interaction is effectively intangibility. Of course, there is one distinct drawback to mirror matter intangibility. The being is still attracted by gravity, so not only would it pass through the solid matter of a wall it would sink through the floor and the ground.

There is also a minor matter of how the being could convert its matter from ordinary matter into mirror matter and back again. This is likely to require astronomically large amounts of energy every time a conversion happened.

More technical details about mirror matter can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_matter)

Comment: I think this might actually work pretty well. I could probably hand-wave the gravity issue, but with enough thought I might be able to get around that.

Comment: @DonielF It's likely the world as we know will vanish. See Theraot's answer for some reasons. If the intangibility is a brief process, then a person could pass through a wall by lining it, go intangible, move where the wall was, & be on the other side when they snap back to tangibility. I'll let you hand-wave away the gravity problem. Have fun fun with the idea.

Comment: @DonielF I can actually think of more problems if the subject changes from tangible to intangible and back. I have updated my answer with that, and in fact, I came up with a solution for the process.

Answer (score 1):

Fermions "collide" as they follow the Pauli Exclusion Principle, while bosons pass freely. No, you won't have it made of bosons, it won't be able to hold any structure, and instead it will dissipate as radiation at the speed of light (on whatever medium they are).

---

### The intangible body

One idea for alternative physics is to have multiple sets of particles that "collide" with each other, but not with the particles of the other sets.

The problem with this idea is that if you have these alternative fermions interact with bosons the same way regular fermions do - so they interact with light, for instance, allowing you to see a body made of them - they would in effect interact with regular fermions because bosons serve as carrier particles!

The bosons are the ones that carry the forces from a fermion to another. So if fermions and alternative fermions interact with bosons, they will also interact by all the forces including the electromagnetic force! Meaning that electrons and alternative electron repel! That means that you can't force an atom and an alternative atom through each other.

---

The thing is you need all the interactions to be internally consistent on the body that "phases". So, molecules continue to keep their structure, and chemical reactions work in equivalent fashion to how they used to work in a regular body. This means that you need all the fundamental forces to continue to work on the body that "phases".

Now, if you say that there a set of alternative fermions and a set of alternative bosons. Then the problem is that the body that "phases" can't interact with anything - maybe except gravity. There is no floor for it, it doesn't reflect light, and a person made of the stuff won't be able to pick up regular object, let alone eat them.

One interesting consequence of the existence of these particles is that there is no reason why they are rarer than the regular particles. So, if you will, they were created in equal abundance from the creation of the cosmos, and they would have followed a similar path to the regular particles, creating galaxies and stars. In fact, if you will, they interact by gravitation, meaning that it is perfectly plausible to have an star and an alternative star in the same place, and similarly with all heavenly bodies.

---

The only way to really make it work, is to have the intangible body do not interact with electromagnetism, nor with the nuclear wear and strong forces. So, the intangible body is invisible, furthermore, a person made of it can't see any tangible objects - although that person could see any other intangible stuff that may be around.

---

From now on I'll put "intangible" and "tangible" in quotes, because really you don't become intangible, you just change from being tangible to regular stuff to be tangible on "the other side".

---

### The process

The question says "Ignoring how it happens in the first place", so I assumed we are talking about a body that is permanently "intangible".

But if we are talking about a body that can willingly change from "tangible" to "intangible" and back that brings other considerations...

You have to convert each particle of the body to it's alternative counterpart. If there is some process that you can use to convert a particle to its counterpart, and all the physics of the alternative particles is identical to that of the regular particles then there is an equivalent process to it backwards.

The above implies that there exists some form of interaction that affects on both kinds of particles.

---

Now, arguably this process would use some amount of energy. Yet... since the initial condition and the final condition would - in theory - have the same mass and energy, we would say that the conversion is 100% efficient. At this point you may even choose to say that it is spontaneous, if no energy is added or lost. It may just happen.

The problem with "it just happens" is that there wouldn't be a way to control it. There would be no way to trigger it to happen, and in fact it would naturally happen all the time! Matter would spontaneously go "intangible" and back and that would have nasty results (see: The location problem).

[@a4android said "the world as we know will vanish"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/53405/how-could-intangibility-be-explained#comment150467_53414) - well this is worse; it would have never come to be.

---

If you want the world to resemble our reality and still have "phasing" as a special thing... it can't be spontaneous. Instead we would say that particles are in some form on equilibrium when they are on the regular form on in their alternative form. And we need to input some amount of energy to break this equilibrium and "push them" to become their counterpart.

With that said, the trick must either be:

- The amount of energy: you need to supply a huge amount of energy in order to start the process. The problem with this idea is that if you want to keep all regular physics the way they are, the amount of energy must be greater than that of all the phenomena that we can humans have been able to do - because we are yet to be able to get these alternative particles - so the amount of energy must be greater than that used in the stronger particle accelerator to date. That means we are talking about a highly energetic process, one that humans will not survive... So, I guess, we discard this option.
- The kind of energy: it is simpler to add new kinds of bosons. So these bosons would be the quanta of a new field - I'll call it Odybly^1 - so there would be an Odybly Field, and there are Odybly bosons. Now, each regular particle has a positive Odybly charge - because scientist would prefer to say that we are the positives ones -, and each alternative particle has a negative Odybly charge. How do you convert from regular to alternative (ie: "tangible" to "intangible") Remove Odybly, and to go back add Odybly. How to add or remove Odybly? Blast with Odybly bosons of the correct charge.

^1: Courtesy of the [Random Word Machine](http://randomwordmachine.com/)

---

### The problems

**The partial body problem**

Now, let's say you want to phase your head to "the other side" of the wall to see what's there. You would make your head "intangible" (i.e. made of alternative particle, i.e. with negative Odybly charge) and now you have disconnected your head from the rest of your body! The body falls dead to ground, and your head will soon suffocate and suffer a painful intangible death... blood and "intangible" blood everywhere.

Not good.

You can't "phase" a portion of your body. In fact, unless the process is full body and instantaneous, you are mutilating yourself every time!

**The location problem**

Let's assume there is an "intangible" planet in the same location where Earth is, so that when you are "intangible" there is some ground^2. And let's say that there is some form of air that you can breathe there... That's not the problem.

The problem is when going back, in the location where you come back... there was air there - assuming you avoided being impaled - and that air can't share location with you!

The non-realistic solution is that the air quickly moves away. It is more realistic to think that the air merges with your body changing its chemistry... but, there is no reason to believe that the air molecules will survive! Entering the "tangible" plain may trigger a nuclear reaction! Now you are dead and you have destroyed the landscape of the place.

Note: I don't know if fission or fusion, but nasty!

^2: well, ground isn’t certain. “The other side” may have evolved the same way our world did, with a human-like civilization and all… or it may be inhabited by some alien species, or it may be a desert planet, or it may be covered in molten lava or be completely frozen… or there may not be a planet at all! May just be just some asteroids, or nothing. Depending on how deterministic you choose to say the universe is. I'll pretend it is a desert planet.

**The void problem**

Let's say that you go "intangible"... where you were, now there is nothing "tangible". You have created a void! Air quickly expands and rushes in to fill the void smashing with itself and high speed, and resulting in a strong sonic wave that expands outwards. You made a thunder! (Not to be confused with a flash, nor a lightning, thunder is the audio part).

**The will problem**

If we are thinking about a person that can go "intangible" and back at will, it means that there is some way in which this person can trigger a Odybly boson shower. There must be some kind of machinery - or a organ if you prefer^3 - to do it.

^3: Make it an implant or a mutation or something like that.

---

### Solutions

So, we need:

- Odybly of the correct charge
- Something to do with the void left behind
- Something to do with whatever obstacle is in "the other side"

If the subject is "tangible", a good source of Odybly of the correct charge is the "intangible" particles around. Conversly if the subject is "intangible" a good source of Odyble is the "tangible" particles around. Once you move the Odybly the "tangible" becomes "intangible" and the "intangible" becomes "tangible".

So, it works like an exchange. When you go "intangible", the place where you were would be filled with the "intangible" stuff that now is tangible. Then you walk to where you want to be and become "tangible", when you do, whatever was "tangible" there would become "intangible".

The amount of Odybly must match, so if there is less Odybly on "the other side" - the substance there is less dense - it may require taking a greater volume. So, there would be a "center" point of the process and from there nearby particles will be affected in such way that the mass of "tangible" and "intangible" matches - and never less that than needed to move the whole body, so no death or mutilation.

Note: the volume taken will rarely be a sphere, in practice it would depend on the density of the stuff there. I would expect that taking a chunk of the floor to be a common thing.

The amount of energy for the apparatus would be proportional to the amount of mass exchanged, and the proportion would be a new universal constant, make it whatever you want it to be.

This means, that using the same apparatus you can make "intangible" yourself, and also your clothing, anything you are touching, a portion of the ground, or even a whole building... depending on the amount of energy used. But remember that what is left in that place is some random stuff that was "intangible" there before.

---

Side effects:

- The partial body problem is not really solved. I'm just assuming that the process is fast enough for a living being to survive, and that the user is not dumb enough to not trigger the process unless it will take the whole body.
- Since the process would be moving something of a different density, it would still cause a difference of pressure in the surrounding. Thunders are still possible.
- The location problem is solved by engineering the apparatus to exchange "intangible" and "tangible". We would have to choose to say that free Odybly bosons have a very short half-life, otherwise it would be feasible to build a machine that moves Odybly bosons from a place to another causing that nasty nuclear reaction of "the location problem". Note: it would still be possible but it won’t be cheaper than doing it by the means we know in our reality.
- If you are "intangible", they can make you "tangible" by using the same apparatus on the place where you are. By doing so, they make you "tangible" and make some other stuff "intangible".
- It is very easy to make a hole in any structure - given enough energy - by making it "intangible", but beware that some random stuff may come from "the other side".
- If you become "intangible" and there is another person who also becomes "intangible" nearby, you will see them on "the other side".
- You may run out of energy to come back.

---

### Cosmic view

What I have described so far was designed as trickery to allow "phasing". But it describes a kind of universe that is divided in two versions. In fact, these versions have symmetry, and internally their physics is equivalent to the real life version - except where it comes to Odybly.

Now, we have said that Odybly only have two charge values (positive and negative), but there is no reason to stop there. You could add more possible values and now you have more versions of the universe to access - or alternative dimensions if you will - with the characteristic that gravity carries over from one to the neighbors and the amount of energy to go from one to another depends on the charge difference (or dimension number if you will).

So, this is actually a blueprint to create fictional universes with dimensions. These other dimensions are not other universes, they are not separate timelines - although they may have similar history - they are all on top of each other but unable to interact, and they have the same physics.

Note that going from one to the other is not done by a portal, but instead by switching places with something on the other dimension. Although it would be possible to create building dedicated to moving to another dimension, the argument of the post is that this is done by a portable device and at personal level.

---

### Scientific revolution

When technology allows to do the travel to "the other side", we have a new place to mine! a new place to live! And only the elite have the technology to do go there!

So, this will become a new source of wealth, a new source of food. And it may become additional living space if that is the path society decides to take.

This would have application in warfare, from a new way to destroy enemy structures to a new way to deploy units, and of course it will serve a new battleground.

And for engineering, there will be the possibility to build systems that have a part on one side and a part on the other. A particular idea is to create manufacturing infrastructure - automatic if possible - on "the other side". So that we can send - or mine there - the raw materials, build, and ship back.

There may be interesting applications in nanotechnology if you can transport atoms or particles with precision from one side to the other. Perhaps cold fusion is possible by these means.

Consider also the possibility that scientists find a civilization there. First contact may not happen by an spacecraft, but by trying to "phase".

Society implications are beyond the scope of the post.

Comment: I have not really come up with an explanation of how you do make Odybly move, what kind of energy conversion would be required, and why it doesn't happen in nature. Without that, I guess I would call this "highly scientific magic" - but what is required is coming up with the mechanism - I have assumed this is some sort of device you carry, but a similar explanation may work for portals - maybe leaving it open for the time being is better, as It allows each author to use it as they see fit.

Comment: Excellent analysis! Glad to see a detailed exploration of the concept, the problems and its consequences. I was aware of most of them, but I assumed if this was a practical working technology all those problems would be solved.